# Typescript + Framer motion "inferred type of 'Wrapper' cannot be named without a reference to"

Tags: typescript, styled-components, framer-motion

I have a react components library that I am using vite to bundle my components with however I am running into a typescript error only with my `framer-motion` components.

**Error**

`The inferred type of 'Wrapper' cannot be named without a reference to '../theme/node_modules/framer-motion/dist'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.`

**Component.styled.ts**

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

export const Wrapper = styled(motion.div)<StyledProps>`
   ... Styling Here
`
```

The confusing part to me is why it is looking into a linked workspace I currently have named as 'theme' for this instead of inside of its own node_modules package.

Because this is a component library package I have framer-motion inside of peerDependencies.

**package.json**

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "18.14.0",
  ...
  "framer-motion": "10.12.4",
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us how and where you import this package ? do you only import `styled` ? which node's version are ya using ?

Comment: Hi @Paul-Marie I have updated the question. I have plenty of other components made with styled components and they dont seem to have any issues, only when I am using `motion.div` is there an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not sure why but wrapper does not infer its type from the motion.div inside  a pnpm mono repo but will in my other projects. I solved this by manually assigning the type to `Wrapper`

```
export const Wrapper: StyledComponent<
    ForwardRefComponent<HTMLDivElement, HTMLMotionProps<'div'>>,
    any,
    StyledProps,
    never
> = styled(motion.div)<StyledProps>`
```